# Unable to connect to MongoDB from Wifi

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I am able to connect via my personal hotspot. When I connect my laptop to my phone's hotspot, I am able to connect to my MongoDB cluster. But when I am on my work's Wifi, or when I deploy to Heroku, they are unable to connect and I get either a timeout or the error

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND test-shard-00-00-xxghh.mongodb.net
```

Any suggestions? I'm not sure where to go from here. Network access in Atlas is set to `0.0.0.0`, allowing anyone to connect.

Comment: is anyone else working on the same project on the same network? do they have the same problem?

Comment: It's just me, one person.

Comment: @MikeK I am having this issue, but slight differently. MongoDB is connecting on any wifi, but not on my mobile hotspot.